# FireFox Redirect URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, plugins

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to redirect a URL in FireFox to another URL.  At this point I'm just trying to get every page entered in FireFox to redirect to Google, but I can't even get that to work.  Once I figure out how to redirect every page to google.com, then I'll add all the conditionals and such to make the plugin useful. Here is the code I have come up with so far.

```
var httpRequestObserver = {
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {

            Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
            httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI("http://google.com", null, null));

  }
}

  get observerService() {
    return Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
  },

  register: function() {
    this.observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
  },

  unregister: function() {
    this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension "Redirector" for Firefox now allows you to automatically redirects to user-defined urls on certain pages.

The Redirector Firefox add-on can be found at the following url:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search

Comment: 7 years later I get an answer 

Thanks though!